Is aux inversion okay in this sentence?
My original sentence is

It is rare insofar as outcomes can be assessed and methods adapted.

If I want to make ‘can’ modify both assess and accept, is it okay to invert ‘can’ like this?

It is rare insofar as can outcomes be assessed and methods adapted.

Because it sounds appropriate when I say it out loud:)

This question is similar to: English Subject-auxiliary inversion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. True, the answer to your question is only 'no' by default (this doesn't include a trigger for inversion mentioned there) ... but it sounds totally unacceptable to my ears.

Can outcomes be assessed and [can] methods be adapted? You are making the sentence more complicated.

This is suspiciously like I want to know if this sentence {The error element of their professional trial-and-error is rarely consequential insofar as can outcomes be rapidly assessed and methods adapted.}  is grammatically correct, which was recently closed.
